# Communication with CDC ACM device on Linux via USB

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I've got some serial device connected via CDC-ACM USB device so it is possible to communicate with it via /dev/ttyACM1 from Linux perspective. 
The end device is the device which contains RTC which allows me to get the current date and time from it via CDC-ACM. It is working fine form user space.

Below is the device descriptor of my CDC-ACM USB device:

```
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            2 
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0xyyyy 
  idProduct          0xzzzz 
  bcdDevice            2.00
  iManufacturer           1 xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  iProduct                2 yyyyyyyyyyyyyy
  iSerial                 3 zzzzzzzzzzzzzz
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           67
    bNumInterfaces          2
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xc0
      Self Powered
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         2 
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 
      iInterface              0 
      CDC Header:
        bcdCDC               1.10
      CDC Call Management:
        bmCapabilities       0x00
        bDataInterface          1
      CDC ACM:
        bmCapabilities       0x02
          line coding and serial state
      CDC Union:
        bMasterInterface        0
        bSlaveInterface         1 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval             255
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass        10 
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered
```

Now - I'd like to set date and time via this CDC-ACM connection using kernel API via USB. I thought that it is enough to send the same request string for date and time via bulk-out ep1 and receive the response via bulk-in ep81. I tried to do it with usb_bulk_msg() and when I'm sending request string with this proc - it returns 0. Next, when I'm sending request for reading response from this device I get -110 (-ETIMEDOUT).

Seems like the linux kernel is sending my first request properly because it returns 0, but for some reasons this request is not received by the end device because it doesn't responded with anything because timeout (-110) occured.

I'm wondering if I didn't miss something with my code and that is why it is not working. Any ideas what can be wrong?

Is it enough to use just only bulk-in and bulk-out endpoints to communicate with end device or anything else should be done before the right transmission?

Comment: Since you have a CDC-ACM connection and claim that you want to use it, then why are you using *"bulk-out ep1 and receive the response via bulk-in ep81"*?  You have a USB serial terminal, and should be using **open("/dev/ttyACM1", ...)**,  **read()**, and **write()**.

Comment: Because I want to set date and time *before* the /dev/ttyACM1 will be accessible for user. I just want to set date as soon as it possible.

Comment: Do it as udev hook. What’s the problem?

Comment: udev = user space and it is too late. I would like to set date before systemd is starting. Systemd has its own loging system so it should start with properly set date and time.